# How can I make the main category page?

Tags: python, django

**Greetings!** I have the following code:

**urls.py**

```
re_path(r'^category/(?P<hierarchy>.+)/$', show_category, name='category'),
```

**views.py**

```
def show_category(request, hierarchy=None):
    category_slug = hierarchy.split('/')
    parent = None
    root = Categories.objects.all()

for slug in category_slug[:-1]:
    parent = root.get(parent=parent, slug=slug)

try:
    instance = Categories.objects.get(parent=parent, slug=category_slug[-1])
except:
    instance = get_object_or_404(Goods, slug=category_slug[-1])
    return render(request, "shop/product.html", {'instance': instance})
else:
    return render(request, 'shop/categories.html', {'instance': instance})
```

The category model has the structure:
*id, slug, imagePath, parent*

I googled a lot and didn't find a good answer to my question. Please help, this script displays only categories at localhost/category/(name of the parent category) and one level higher. **And the problem is that I can't make the main category page at all (localhost/category)**, please help or point me in the right direction to solve this issue!

I'm going crazy trying to solve this problem. Tried and google and dig into the documentation. Can't decide at all.

Comment: Well, you don't have an URL that would match `/category/` at all for one. What would the "main category page" show?

Comment: @AKX List of parent categories, and their subcategories

Comment: As well as their information by type, pictures and so on.

Comment: @AKX That is, you need to make a separate URL for /category/ itself?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but you will need to adjust the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjust your regexp to

```
re_path(r'^category/(?P<hierarchy>.*)$', show_category, name='category'),
```

it will also match just `category/`.

You can then edit your view to something like

```
def show_category(request, hierarchy=None):
   hierarchy = (hierarchy or "").strip("/")
   if hierarchy:
       category_slug = hierarchy.split('/')
       parent = None
       for slug in category_slug[:-1]:
           parent = Categories.objects.get(parent=parent, slug=slug)
       category = Categories.objects.get(parent=parent, slug=category_slug[-1])
   else:
       category = None
       
   if category:
       return render(request, 'shop/categories.html', {'instance': category})
   # No category, show top-level content somehow
   return ...
```

Comment: Sorry friend, I'm very stupid, I specified "categories = Categories.objects.all()" at the end of your code and after "return render(request, 'shop/categories.g.html', context)". The "context" is 'instance': categories. But it doesn't display anything on the main category page.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you tell me how to bring this to my mind!

Comment: That would depend entirely on what your `categories.g.html` does.